# How to connect to the Twitter API from AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, twitter

How to connect Twitter api from AngularJS?

```
$http.get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json).then(function(data){
$scope.data = data;
},
function(error){
});
```

Comment: why arent you using angular? its a lot easier to use and will probably work better for you

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 1):

Use ngTweet as a dependency `angular.module('myApp', ['ngtweet']);`

add the tag into your template

```
<twitter-timeline>
    <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/IAmAru/lists/food-
        trucks" data-widget-id="673710543212052480"> Tweets from 
        https://twitter.com/IAmAru/lists/food-trucks</a>
</twitter-timeline>
```

sauce:  https://github.com/arusahni/ngtweet